# execution of pg_dump on a standby server

Tags: postgresql

I am using physical replication with 1 standby in postgres v.14.4. The `max_standby_archive_delay` and `max_standby_streaming_delay` parameters are configured by default at 30s. if a pg_dump is executed on the standby side will the snapshot taken during data export be consistent despite small values for these parameters.

Comment: It will be consistent, or it will fail.  The recourse for those parameters is to kill the queries, not to return bogus results.

Answer (score 0):

The pg_dump will be consistent, but obviously not at exactly the same point in time as one run simultaneously on your primary.

Note that longer-running transactions can be aborted on the standby if your replication configuration is set up to do so.

---

Clarification: Yes, of course the dump as a whole will be consistent - it would be useless otherwise. The program executes all its queries in a single snapshot. If you run it a second time, the second snapshot will be different from the first, but each dump will be internally consistent.

Comment: What do you mean by consistent, if we export a schema, all tables for this schema will be consistent.